# UITableView style with background image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is there any way to do UITableView background like on this image programmatically? I mean to do top and left borders dark and right and bottom white. If it's impossible how can I implement it with one image (my UITableViewCell's could have different height)? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this great tutorial  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Basically change background image inside this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 /// some code....

UIImage *rowBackground;
UIImage *selectionBackground;
NSInteger sectionRows = [aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
}
else if (row == 0)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected.png"];
}
else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"];
}
else
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRow.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"];
}
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;

// more code...
```

You shoud use only middle row, because this code has 3 images, one for first row, one for last row and one for middle row.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use coregraphic's EOClip to cut out the shape of the main box, and then apply 2 dropshadows of 1 pixel size each.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using Core Graphics.

See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) for a tutorial on how to use Core Graphics.

Note that this might be a lot more complex and involving for what you want to achieve, and easier solutions may exist, but if all else fails, CG will definitely work :).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small square png image of a black semi-transparent rounded rect with the highlights and shadows on its border.

Then you make a `UIImageView` with `imageView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0)` an set it as a background view for your table or cells.

Comment: Very easy to implement. Thanks!